# Multiple keyframe animations break custom slider in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, css, slider, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

EDIT:
Added [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p1uqzwsm/)

We made a custom image slider with jQuery and CSS3 keyframe animations. This image slider works perfectly in all browsers except for IE11. We think it has something to do with simultaneous animations.

Basically if you are navigating through the slider. It will add and remove a class from the previous slide and add a new one to the current one. You will add these classes: *`.slide-display-top`* or *`.slide-display-bottom`* based on the direction. After adding, two `child-divs` will start animating from the bottom and top of the screen.

It does work when you navigate back and forth.

Live version:

http://creativeforce.nl

We are really stuck at this one.

Part of the css:

```
body main .slider .slide-display-top {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    body main .slider .slide-display-top>div {
        height: 100%}
    body main .slider .slide-display-top>div:first-child {
        -webkit-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
    }
    body main .slider .slide-display-top>div:last-child {
        -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
    }
    body main .slider .slide-display-bottom {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    body main .slider .slide-display-bottom>div {
        height: 100%}
    body main .slider .slide-display-bottom>div:first-child {
        -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        animation: moveFromTopFade 700ms ease-in-out;
    }
    body main .slider .slide-display-bottom>div:last-child {
        -webkit-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
        animation: moveFromBottomFade 700ms ease-in-out;
    }
```

Keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        transform: translate(0, -100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        transform: translate(0, -100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        transform: translate(0, -100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-o-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        transform: translate(0, -100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes moveFromTopFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
        transform: translate(0, -100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-o-keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a fix for it. For some reason, translate() did not work when animating two divs at the same time. Instead of this:

```
@keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
        transform: translate(0, 100%)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
}
```

We used this:

```
@keyframes moveFromBottomFade {
    0% {
         position:absolute;
         bottom:-100%;
    }
    100% {
         position:absolute;
         bottom:0%;
    }
}
```

Everything works smooth now. Thank you internet explorer....